# Convert python datetime to timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

How do I convert a human-readable time such as `20.12.2016 09:38:42,76` to a Unix timestamp in **milliseconds**?

Comment: You need to provide an appropriate format string to `datetime.datetime.strptime`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 134, accepted):

In Python 3 this can be done in 2 steps:

1. Convert timestring to `datetime` object
2. Multiply the timestamp of the `datetime` object by 1000 to convert it to milliseconds.

For example like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_obj = datetime.strptime('20.12.2016 09:38:42,76',
                           '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S,%f')
millisec = dt_obj.timestamp() * 1000

print(millisec)
```

Output:

```
1482223122760.0
```

`strptime` accepts your timestring and a format string as input. The timestring (first argument) specifies *what* you actually want to convert to a `datetime` object. The format string (second argument) specifies the actual *format* of the string that you have passed.

Here is the explanation of the format specifiers from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

- `%d` - Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%m` - Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%Y` - Year with century as a decimal number
- `%H` - Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%M` - Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%S` - Second as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%f` - Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded to 6 digits.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Unfortunately I got the error "AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'". Possibly because I am using Python 2.7?

Comment: Yes. Use MYGz's answer for Python 2.7

Answer (score 35):

For those who search for an answer without parsing and losing milliseconds,
given `dt_obj` is a datetime:

**python3 only, elegant**

```
int(dt_obj.timestamp() * 1000)
```

**both python2 and python3 compatible:**

```
import time

int(time.mktime(dt_obj.utctimetuple()) * 1000 + dt_obj.microsecond / 1000)
```

Answer (score 14):

For Python2.7 - modifying MYGz's answer to not strip milliseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime("20.12.2016 09:38:42,76", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S,%f").strftime('%s.%f')
d_in_ms = int(float(d)*1000)
print(d_in_ms)

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(float(d)))
```

Output:

```
1482248322760
2016-12-20 09:38:42.760000
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to parse your time format using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

```
>>> import time
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> ts, ms = '20.12.2016 09:38:42,76'.split(',')
>>> ts
'20.12.2016 09:38:42'
>>> ms
'76'
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(ts, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
>>> time.mktime(dt.timetuple())*1000 + int(ms)*10
1482223122760.0
```

Answer (score 4):

For Python2.7

You can format it into seconds and then multiply by 1000 to convert to millisecond.

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime("20.12.2016 09:38:42,76", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S,%f").strftime('%s')
d_in_ms = int(d)*1000
print(d_in_ms)

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(float(d)))
```

Output:

```
1482206922000
2016-12-20 09:38:42
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I copy and paste your code and got a "ValueError: Invalid format string".

Comment: @Tom Python version? It's working for me on Python2.7.6

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.12.

Comment: That strips out the ,76 though so it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for a python 2.7 answer

Comment: It will ignore millisecond in string. And won't solve the problem.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.16, saying `ValueError: Invalid format string`. I guess it's b/c `%s` is not supported. Only `%S` is supported.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of these answers don't preserve the milliseconds from the datetime. This works for me

```
def datetime_to_ms_epoch(dt):
    microseconds = time.mktime(dt.timetuple()) * 1000000 + dt.microsecond
    return int(round(microseconds / float(1000)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple python 2.7 / 3 solution for converting python datetime to timestamp (as int) as title suggests. Use datetime.strptime to convert string to datetime object if your input is a string.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt_obj = datetime.utcnow()  # input datetime object
```

milliseconds

```
int(float(dt_obj.strftime('%s.%f')) * 1e3)

1656096296215
```

microseconds

```
int(float(dt_obj.strftime('%s.%f')) * 1e6)

1656096296215242
```