# Convert a datetime string to millisecond UNIX time stamp

Tags: java, python, datetime, time

I'm trying to correlate the timing information obtain from a java job and linux performance monitoring tool `perf` (specifically `perf stat`).

The timing information from java is obtained using 
`String tstamp0 = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());` (This is essentially time in milliseconds from epoch)
whereas `perf` gives the time the process has began and the subsequent recording only show the time elapsed.

What I would like to do is, convert the timing information obtained from the `perf stat` to milliseconds, and here is where I'm failing. I'm approaching this problem in `Python`.

This piece of code is giving me the timing information from `perf`

```
tailit = "head -n 1 " + dataset_path
process = subprocess.Popen(tailit, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
date_time = out.split("\n")[0].split(" ")[4:]
date = date_time[3] + "-" + date_time[0] + "-" +  date_time[1]
time = date_time[2]
#TIMESTAMP

INIT_TIME = datetime.datetime.strptime(date + ' ' + time, "%Y-%B-%d %H:%M:%S") + datetime.timedelta(seconds=0.01)
#df is pandas data frame
df['STAMPME'] = df['TCOUNT'].apply(lambda x: foobar(datetime.timedelta(seconds=x) + INIT_TIME))
```

here foobar is the following to convert a string to timestamp in milliseconds, but it doesn't make sense.

```
def foobar(INIT_TIME):
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(INIT_TIME), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strftime('%s')
    d_in_ms = int(d)*1000
    return (d_in_ms)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Prior questions were not addressing the problem of correlating the `java timestamp (currentTimeMillis())` to the datetime with milliseconds.

For instance: with the function `foobar`:
with INIT_TIME set as `2017-05-11 10:56:54.203`, the return value is `1494493014000` when it instead should be `1494500214203`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime)

Comment: @luoluo I tried that... but didn't help.

Comment: In what way didn’t help? How was it insufficient of failed?

Comment: It doesn't show to how convert a datetime to timestamp milliseconds.. (similar to how currentTimeMillis in Java does.)
Also tried this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635547/convert-python-datetime-to-timestamp-in-milliseconds

Comment: @OleV.V.: I gave an example above now

Comment: `>>> (datetime.datetime(2012,04,01,0,0) - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think figured out the problem. 
Looks like `foobar` function is returning time in GMT+2, whereas the java job was returning time in `GMT`. so with a timedelta of `+2`, I could solve it.